# Loopback relations

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

Hi I'm  trying this example 
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasAndBelongsToMany+relations
I have these two models :

**Part**

```
{
  "name": "Part",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "partNumber": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
      "parts": {
        "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
        "model": "Assembly",
        "foreignKey": ""
      }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**Assembly**

```
{
  "name": "Assembly",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "parts": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "Part",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

When I try to add a element in assembly I have a undefined element.

I'm using

**assembly.js**

```
Assembly.parts.add(part, function(err) {
  ...
});
```

but assembly.parts is undefined.

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a static method on `Assembly` that is wrong.

Relation methods should used as prototype methods. That make sense.

So you can call like this :

```
assembly_instance.parts.add(...
```